# 'ncat' considers redirection as (additional) port specification when run from python script

Tags: python, netcat

In a python script I am trying to run a subrocess that listens and recives a file using `ncat`:

```python
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where the `command` variable is this list:

```python
command = ['nc', '-4', '-l', '10099', '>', '/tmp/files/copy_file_2_10099']
```

And I get the error:

```
Ncat: Got more than one port specification: 10000 > *path to file*
```

It seems like it sees the `>` and path strings as port numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that as far as `nc` can tell you are providing `>` and `/tmp/files/copy_file_2_10099` as the final 2 parameters.

The python Popen function in the `subprocess` module does not do shell redirection, so it just passes those two arguments as additional parameters. The reason why this works when run in a shell is that the shell interprets the `> /tmp/files/copy_file_2_10099` before passing the parameters to the command, so the command never sees them.  The shell handles opening the file and using its file descriptor for the commands standard output.

It’s possible to add a `shell=True` parameter to Popen, but it is [reccomended that you pass a string instead of a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)(an array, like you did). If you do that, Popen launches a shell to run the command and it will handle the redirection.

If you want to capture the output of the command in pure python, it is possible to tell subprocces.Popen to use a file object by supplying a `stdout` (or `stderr`) parameter to your Popen call.

Comment: I tried passing a pure string (did command=" ".join(command)) but now I get the error: 
No such file or directory: 'nc -4 -l 10099 > *path to file*.

Comment: Are you sure you also added shell=True?

Comment: I didn't. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [`subprocess.Popen()` takes the optional named argument `shell`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), that can be set to `True` to run the command line through the shell.

Without it (default), it just passes the strings given as raw arguments to the command. With it, you probably should give the command line as a single string. E.g. with `subprocess.run()`:

```
# raw strings, no shell
>>> proc = subprocess.run(["echo", "$$"])
$$

# with the shell
>>> proc = subprocess.run("echo shell pid is $$", shell=True)
shell pid is 14897

# this passes the first as the shell command line and others as $0, $1, $2
>>> args=['echo "$# args, arg #2 is: $2"', "sh", "abc", "def"]
>>> proc = subprocess.run(args, shell=True)
2 args, arg #2 is: def
```

So you probably want

```
command = "nc -1 -l 10099 > /tmp/files/copy_file_2_10099"
proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Or you could deal with the redirection yourself, just open the file in Python and pass it via `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually specifically want to use shell=FALSE in order to test something. How can I run this command in the process without the shell?

Comment: @דורוןבןשושן, `f = open("/tmp/...10099", "w"); proc = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=f)` or something like that. Not sure if you need `.Popen()` really, it seems to me `.run()` should do